DAX query for average time taken per hour
I would like to find the average time taken for each hour, where the status is 200 using a DAX query.
So between 20:00 and 21:00, the average time taken is X seconds


First you'd have to create a measure:
AvgTime = AVERAGEX(
   FILTER('tablename','tablename'[Status]=200),
[time_taken])

As for the "for each hour" part, You'd need to add a column to your table that returns the hour of the time column, because that would be on columns or rows in your matrix.
